# Horizontal scroll of grid with items width equal to its content

Tags: javascript, css, css-grid

How do I make a container with horizontal scroll of its items with an item's width equal to its content(like `max-content`) using css grid.

I tried this

```
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat('dynamic value eq to no. of items', max-content);
height: 100%;
gap: 10px;
```

This does not work and I want to avoid using `max-content` because I read there is not much browser support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `grid-auto-flow` and `grid-auto-columns` to achieve the horizontal scroll. Then utilize `minmax()` to specify each grid items size. With a minimum value of `8rem` (or another value of your choosing) and a maximum value of `auto` to replace `max-content` since there isn't full browser support for that sizing keyword.

Using `auto` as the maximum value is identical to using `max-content`. As a minimum it represents the largest minimum size (as specified by min-width/min-height) of the grid items occupying the grid track. [minmax() - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/minmax())

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  height: 100%;
  gap: 10px;
  grid-auto-columns: minmax(8rem, auto);
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.blue {
  background: lightblue;
  height: 8rem;
  /* height: auto; use auto to allow the content to determine grid items height */
}
```

```html
<section class="grid">
  <div class="blue">1</div>
  <div class="blue">2</div>
  <div class="blue">3</div>
  <div class="blue">4</div>
  <div class="blue">5</div>
  <div class="blue">6</div>
  <div class="blue">7</div>
  <div class="blue">8</div>
</section>
```